# Android car bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to develop a feature for my Android app, which includes checking whether my device is connected to a car.

I can, in theory, use the device class provided by (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html), and check for `AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO`, but in practice, we've seen that most cars use `AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE`.

What recourse do I have here to better detect cars?

I read a similar post to this from 2013, but there was no hard answer given then. I was hoping that 6 years later there might be.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `UUIDs` sent by a Bluetooth device during `SDP(Service Discovery Protocol)` discovery, in which Bluetooth devices send the services they can provide.

You can find `UUIDs` in `BluetoothUuid.java` class [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothUuid.java).

Here you can see

```
public static final ParcelUuid Handsfree =
            ParcelUuid.fromString("0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

Devices such as headsets, car-kit, etc. will send this `UUID` in their `SDP` response.
You can find all `UUIDs` sent by a Bluetooth device like this:

```
bluetoothDevice.getUuids()
```

It will return array of `ParcelUuid`. You can check if there is any `UUID` in array that matches with `BluetoothUuid.Handsfree`.